# Object won't display in JTable from event in another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm a little ignorant when it comes to events in Java, so I'm working on a project to help rectify that. As such, I am working on a project that is basically a pizzeria POS program. There's the main GUI, with the pre-configured "meal" options. I click on those, and their price and names are displayed in the JTable correctly. However, when I try doing that with a button in a different class, I get no errors and no entries into the JTable.

I'm using NetBeans GUI Builder btw.

This is currently what I have for the MainGUI class:

```java
public class MainGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   public void getItems(String extName, double extPrice) {
        itemName = extName; //instance variables
        itemPrice = extPrice;
        getTotal(itemPrice); //displays the total sum of items in textfield
        orderTab.setValueAt(itemName, arrayCount, 0); //JTable.
        orderTab.setValueAt(itemPrice, arrayCount, 1);
        arrayCount++; //so next items clicked can displayed on next row
    }
}
```

and for the other class

```java
public class BuildPizzaGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   private void addButtonClick(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                
        MainGUI exporter = new MainGUI();
        exporter.getItems(custName, custPrice);
        setVisible(false); //closes window
   }
}
```

I don't get any errors messages. I want the item name and price to be displayed, but currently, I don't get anything other than a closed window. Thanks.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
MainGUI exporter = new MainGUI();
```

You can't keep creating a new instance of the MainGUI every time you click a button. If you do it means with every item you try to add you create a new JFrame.

Instead you need to pass a reference to the existing MainGUI class when you create your BuildPizzaGUI. Then when you click the button you reference this variable which will allow you to update the JTable in that class.